# Manual Sorting not working?

Tags: java

```
String temp ="";
int Count =0;
String[] names = new String[10];   
for(int a = 0; a<=9; a++)
{

    String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter name");
    names[a]=name;
    Count++;

}
System.out.println("Unchanged: "+Arrays.toString(names));

for(int i=0;i<(Count-1);i++)
{
for(int j=(i+1); j<Count;j++)
{
    if((names[j].compareTo(names[i]))>0)
    {
        temp = names[i];
        names[i] =names[j];
        names[i]=temp;



    }

}
```

}

Hi i'm trying to get this manual sort to work (i know there is a quick sort option but i have to do it this way) and i cannot see what the problem is
any suggestions?

Comment: `names[i]=temp;` => `names[j]=temp;` I guess

Comment: For one, you don't output the sorted array, so how do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: Yeah sorry this got cut off                              System.out.println("Changed: "+Arrays.toString(names));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to swap names[i] and names[j], you better write that this way:

```
    temp = names[i];
    names[i] = names[j];
    names[j] = temp;      // <--- replaced i with j
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) worked perfectly